# Can i use malloc to allocate memory on mmap'd file

Tags: linux, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory, mmap

I want to use malloc but instead of using sbrk to get pages from the kernel i want it to allocate on a memory mapped file. So if my machine suddenly crashes, the process heap will be backed up on that file.

Is there such a malloc library out there?

Comment: Why don't you just enable core dumps `ulimit -c unlimited`?

Comment: What do you mean by machine crash ... a kernel panic? Why do you need application memory state in this situation if the kernel is reason of crash?

Comment: I just want the memory to be persistent, so that if there is a sudden power failure, all the memory will be still on the disk on some file. (I understand that maybe the OS didn't really fsync all the data)

Comment: I am afraid it's impossible with `malloc` but you can check out this project [fmalloc](https://github.com/yasukata/fmalloc) then just alias fmalloc to malloc with the preprocessor for easy exchange between standard malloc and this fmalloc.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use a memory mapped file, use these functions.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: Maybe i wast clear, I want to back up the whole heap to the disk, so during the runtime of a process all its pointers will actually point to the mmap'd file